# Trigonometric inverse functions are not working

Tags: java, android, trigonometry

I am working in android calculator app. My trigonometric inverse functions are working properly in radians case. But in degree case, they are not working properly.

```
if (func.equals("sin"))  x = Math.sin(Math.toRadians(x));
else if (func.equals("cos"))  x = Math.cos(Math.toRadians(x));
else if (func.equals("tan"))  x = Math.tan(Math.toRadians(x));
else if (func.equals("asin")) x = Math.asin(Math.toRadians(x));
else if (func.equals("acos")) x = Math.acos(Math.toRadians(x));
else if (func.equals("atan")) x = Math.atan(Math.toRadians(x));
```

If I round them then `sin(.5)=0.0`, which is wrong?

Comment: Please construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: What type is x? and yes, please give us enough code to actually compile it and see the problem

Comment: His code is sufficient for his question.  You're thinking too much in programming, not enough in math.

Comment: @GabeSechan - Indeed, but the first two lines (and the specific "example" called out) both refer to forward trig functions.

Answer (score 0):

Inverse trig functions don't take radians.  They take values.  asin and acos take values in [-1, 1], atan in [-inf, inf].  You would never do a toRadians on the input of asin/acos/atan, you would do it on the output.

Comment: Thnaks but when i put sin(.5) it gives wrong answer i case of Math.round(Math.sin(Math.toRadians(x))); and if i remove Math.round then it also gives wrong answer if i out 180 in angle

Comment: You put radians into normal trig functions.  You don't into inverse functions.  THink about the math:  sin(x) = y.   Than means asin(y) = x.  Y is not in radians.

Comment: yes i got your point  #Gabe Sechan   but i am asking for simple trig function . They give Wrong answer when angle in greater than 90 or minus . and if i put Math.round then also i get wrong answer